# where could there be a mistake in my assembly language code

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, inline-assembly

I have a program written using assembler insertion in c++ visual studio. I want to arrange it as an assembler procedure in visual studio. And I can't understand why I'm counting incorrectly. I think the problem is in loop_2, but I can't find the error.

here is the code that works

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    const int N = 5; // количество элементов для подсчета количества значений
    int raznost = N / 2; // рассчитывается смещение для отрицательных чисел
    int arr[] = { 1,2,2 };
    int freq[N] = { 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int* result = new int[n];
    _asm {
        xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
        lea eax, arr
        lea ebx, freq
        mov edx, raznost
        //mov edi, n

        imul edx, 4
        add ebx, edx
        loop_1 :
        cmp ecx, n
            je loopend_1
            mov edx, [eax + ecx * 4]
            inc[ebx + edx * 4]
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_1
            loopend_1 :
        lea ebx, freq
            xor edx, edx // для количества элементов в новом массиве
            xor ecx, ecx
            outer_loop :
        cmp ecx, n
            je outer_loopend
            push ecx
            xor ecx, ecx // счетчик
            xor eax, eax // максимальное значение
            xor esi, esi // количество
            mov eax, 0
            loop_2:
        cmp ecx, N
            je loopend_2
            cmp esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            jg end_if
            mov esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            mov eax, ecx
            end_if :
        inc ecx
            jmp loop_2
            loopend_2 :
        xor ecx, ecx
            push ebx
            mov ebx, eax
            push ebx
            mov ebx, result
            sub eax, raznost
            loop_3 :
        cmp esi, ecx
            je loopend_3
            mov[ebx + edx * 4], eax
            inc edx
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_3
            loopend_3:
        pop ebx
            mov ecx, ebx
            pop ebx

            push eax
            mov eax, 0

            mov[ebx + ecx * 4], eax
            pop eax
            pop ecx
            inc ecx
            jmp outer_loop
            outer_loopend:
    }

    /*
        xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
        lea eax, arr
        lea ebx, freq
        mov edx, raznost
        // mov edi, [ebp + 20]
        push ebx;;;
        imul edx, 4
            add ebx, edx
            loop_1 :
        cmp ecx, n
            je loopend_1
            mov edx, [eax + ecx * 4]
            inc dword ptr[ebx + edx * 4]
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_1
            loopend_1 :
        pop ebx;;;; lea ebx freq
            mov edi, edx
            xor edx, edx; для количества элементов в новом массиве
            xor ecx, ecx
            outer_loop :
        cmp ecx, n
            je outer_loopend
            push ecx
            xor ecx, ecx; счетчик
            xor eax, eax; максимальное значение
            xor esi, esi; количество
            mov eax, 0
            loop_2:
        cmp ecx, N
            je loopend_2
            cmp esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            jg end_if
            mov esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            mov eax, ecx
            end_if :
        inc ecx
            jmp loop_2
            loopend_2 :
        xor ecx, ecx
            push ebx
            mov ebx, eax
            push ebx
            mov ebx, result
            sub eax, edi//
            loop_3 :
        cmp esi, ecx
            je loopend_3
            mov[ebx + edx * 4], eax
            inc edx
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_3
            loopend_3 :
        pop ebx
            mov edi, ebx
            pop ebx
            push eax
            mov eax, 0
            mov[ebx + edi * 4], eax
            pop eax



            pop ecx
            inc ecx
            jmp outer_loop
            outer_loopend :
    }*/
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << result[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is the code through the procedure that don't work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int __stdcall Proc1(int* arr, int* freq, int raznost, int n, int N, int* result);
int main() {
    const int N = 5;//2000; // количество элементов для подсчета количества значений
    int raznost = N / 2; // рассчитывается смещение для отрицательных чисел
    int arr[] = { 1,1,2};
    int freq[N] = { 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int* result = new int[n];
    //int result[N] = { 0 };
    Proc1(arr, freq, raznost, n, N, result);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << result[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
.386
PUBLIC _Proc1@24
;PUBLIC _Proc2
;PUBLIC Proc3
;PUBLIC Proc4
;PUBLIC @Proc5@4

.model flat
.data
.code

_Proc1@24 proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    
    
    xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
        xor edx, edx
        mov eax, [ebp + 8]
        mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
        mov edx, [ebp + 16]
        ;mov edi, [ebp + 20]
        ;;;
        imul edx, 4
        add ebx, edx
        ;push ebx
        loop_1 :
        cmp ecx, [ebp + 20]
            je loopend_1
            mov edx, [eax + ecx * 4]
            inc dword ptr [ebx + edx * 4]
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_1
            loopend_1 :
        ;pop ebx 
            xor edx, edx ; для количества элементов в новом массиве
            xor ecx, ecx
            outer_loop :
        cmp ecx, [ebp + 20]
            je outer_loopend
            push ecx
            xor ecx, ecx ; счетчик
            xor eax, eax ; максимальное значение
            xor esi, esi ; количество
            mov eax, 0
            loop_2:
        cmp ecx, [ebp + 24]
            je loopend_2
            cmp esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            jg end_if
            mov esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            mov eax, ecx
            end_if :
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_2
            loopend_2 :
        xor ecx, ecx
            push ebx
            mov ebx, eax
            push ebx
            mov ebx, [ebp + 28]
            sub eax, edx
            loop_3 :
        cmp esi, ecx
            je loopend_3
            mov[ebx + edx * 4], eax
            inc edx
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_3
            loopend_3:
        pop ebx
            mov edi, ebx
            pop ebx
            push eax
            mov eax, 0
            mov [ebx + edi * 4], eax
            pop eax



            pop ecx
            inc ecx
            jmp outer_loop
            outer_loopend:


    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 24
_Proc1@24   endp

end
```

I've been puzzling for a long time why it doesn't work, but I still couldn't find the error

Comment: For starters, standard calling convention mandates `ebx`, `esi` and `edi` have to be preserved.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  If it faults, a debugger will show you which instruction, and you can look at registers to see what was going on, e.g. what address.  Also, this indenting is really hard to read.  Normally we indent labels *less* than code, so we can see them.  And leaving a blank line after the end of a loop helps humans see the logically separate phases of a function.  See [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965) for a style example.

Comment: It would also improve the question if you describe in words what this code is supposed to do, so we know what to look for when reading it.  I don't see any English description or comments anywhere.  See also [mcve].

Comment: this code should sort the array by the frequency of occurrence of numbers. For example, with the array {1,2,2}, it should output {2,2,1}

Answer (score 0):

```
_Proc1@24 proc
push ebp
mov ebp, esp


xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor edx, edx
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
    mov edx, [ebp + 16]
    ;mov edi, [ebp + 20]
    ;;;
    push ebx
    imul edx, 4
    add ebx, edx
    
    loop_1 :
    cmp ecx, [ebp + 20]
        je loopend_1
        mov edx, [eax + ecx * 4]
        inc dword ptr [ebx + edx * 4]
        inc ecx
        jmp loop_1
        loopend_1 :
    pop ebx 
        xor edx, edx ; для количества элементов в новом массиве
        xor ecx, ecx
        outer_loop :
    cmp ecx, [ebp + 20]
        je outer_loopend
        push ecx
        xor ecx, ecx ; счетчик
        xor eax, eax ; максимальное значение
        xor esi, esi ; количество
        mov eax, 0
        loop_2:
    cmp ecx, [ebp + 24]
        je loopend_2
        cmp esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
        jg end_if
        mov esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
        mov eax, ecx
        end_if :
        inc ecx
        jmp loop_2
        loopend_2 :
    xor ecx, ecx
        push ebx
        mov ebx, eax
        push ebx
        mov ebx, [ebp + 28]
        sub eax, [ebp + 16]
        loop_3 :
    cmp esi, ecx
        je loopend_3
        mov[ebx + edx * 4], eax
        inc edx
        inc ecx
        jmp loop_3
        loopend_3:
    pop ebx
        mov edi, ebx
        pop ebx
        push eax
        mov eax, 0
        mov [ebx + edi * 4], eax
        pop eax
        pop ecx
        inc ecx
        jmp outer_loop
        outer_loopend:


mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
ret 24
```

_Proc1@24   endp

Comment: What's the difference between this code and what was in the question?  What bug did you fix?  Without that, no future readers are going to get any benefit from this, including experts looking for existing duplicates to link to beginners when their code has the same problem.  This code still overwrites the caller's EBX, ESI, and EDI without saving them, so you didn't fix that calling-convention bug.  Also, you don't need to xor-zero a register before `mov eax, [ebp + 8]`.  The `mov` overwrites the old value so it doesn't matter what was there.